# How to change button size according to screen's device?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-linearlayout

I have a button with size `width=216` and `height=110` in a device screen resolution is 1080 x 1920.  When I change to other device (smaller resolution), the button is so big. Hence, I need to write a fuction to dynamically change button size according to screen's device resolution. First, I will check target device resolution then I change it based on above my current device. However, the button resolution is not correct. How can I fix it? This is my code

My code in the 1080x1920

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="216dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          />
       </LinearLayout>
```

Changed to dynamic way:

```
    public int WIDTH ;
    public int HEIGHT ;
    //Get screen resolution
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    HEIGHT = metrics.heightPixels;
    WIDTH= metrics.widthPixels;           

    int height_px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 110, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int weight_px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 216, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int width_linearlayout = Math.round((float)weight_px/1080*WIDTH);
    int height_linearlayout = Math.round((float)height_px/1920*HEIGHT);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width_linearlayout,height_linearlayout);
    btn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Did you read through [Supporting Multiple Layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)? If not then I suggest you to go on and have a look.

Comment: @Abbas: It is from xml and drawable folder. I want to change my button using programming

Comment: Then you'll have to do a lot of work worth very little. I suggest you to do it via layouts. Check @slackwars answer that is the best way to achieve what you want. However the solution only works if you have similar layouts. For different layouts for different size you'll have to add multiple layouts instead.

Comment: Because the size of button must be carefully choose according to the reference once. Hence, I need to use code/programming to do it, not xml file

Comment: 1) why do you write e.g. `HEIGHT = metrics.widthPixels;` ? 2) Could you explain / add a picture of what you want vs. what you currently get?  3) If we get everything else to work: as the Button isn't square, this may look fine with portrait only to become an absolute mess in landscape.

Comment: @0X0nosugar: It is my bug. I updated it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do in situations like this is create a specific dimens.xml for different screen size  requirements.

[image: Android studio dimens.xml view]

Each of these would contain parameters specific to devices with screens fitting those dimensions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
  <dimen name="nav_header_height">160dp</dimen>
  <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
  <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="button_size_height">32dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="button_size_width">70dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

No Extra coding, just need to maintain multiple xml files containing your button parameters.

Each dimension would be referenced as such:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/button_size_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_size_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          />
```

Comment: How do you can compute button size for smaller or bigger resolution than reference resolution (my case is `1080 x 1920`)?

Comment: goto:  https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
and scroll down to 
`Using new size qualifiers`

This will give you a quick brief on how to format your project folders to support multiple screen resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use layout_weight in order to achieve what you want, and that will be used by wrapping each row of buttons inside a LinearLayout and all that LinearLayouts plus the TextView will be wrapped inside one big LinearLayout instead of your RelativeLayout like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/disp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="none"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="32sp"
    android:textStyle="normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@drawable/clear_btn" />

    <!-- then the three remaining buttons -->

    <LinearLayout />

    <!-- then the four remaining rows -->


    <!-- in the last row the "0" button will have layout_weight="2" NOT "1" -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hell0. I want to use programming to change button size, not xml

Answer (score 0):

Add folder `values-sw540dp` its is for  **1080p screens**. In this folder add `dimens.xml`

```
  <dimen name="btn_height">100dp</dimen>
  <dimen name="btn_width">65dp</dimen>
```

**Edit your xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          />
       </LinearLayout>
```

**Other resolutions**

```
    values-sw720dp          10.1” tablet 1280x800 mdpi

values-sw600dp          7.0”  tablet 1024x600 mdpi

values-sw480dp          5.4”  480x854 mdpi 
values-sw480dp          5.1”  480x800 mdpi 

values-xhdpi            4.7”   1280x720 xhdpi 
values-xhdpi            4.65”  720x1280 xhdpi 

values-hdpi             4.0” 480x800 hdpi
values-hdpi             3.7” 480x854 hdpi

values-mdpi             3.2” 320x480 mdpi

values-ldpi             3.4” 240x432 ldpi
values-ldpi             3.3” 240x400 ldpi
values-ldpi             2.7” 240x320 ldpi
```

Comment: Sorry. My current resolution is 1080. I want to compute the button resolution for smaller or bigger resolution than my reference resolution using code

Comment: So add other values, set name like in answer and create dimens.